# jQuery slide toggle animation together with other elements

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, toggle

I'm trying to implement slide toggle *from left to right* and vice-versa using jQuery `toggle()`.

Toggle works, but I want the next element to div being toggle to *animate smoothly* parallel to toggle effect.

Check code I tried: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KFmLv/264/)**

**HTML**

```
<button id="button" class="myButton">Run Effect</button>

<div id="myDiv">
    <p>This div will have slide toggle effect.</p>
</div>
<div class="other_details">
    This should move parallel with re-size of div being toggled.  
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".myButton").click(function () {
    var effect = 'slide';
    var duration = 500;
    $('#myDiv').toggle(effect, {direction: "left"}, duration);
});
```

**CSS**

```
#myDiv {
    color:Green;
    background-color:#eee;
    border:2px solid #333;
    text-align:justify;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
}
.other_details{
    float:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:5px;
    margin-left:2px;
}
```

You can see in output, that `"other_details"` div isn't moving parallel with toggle effect. *Its moving only after completion of toggle effect.*

Please help me to get solution.

Comment: I think you will have to wrap both of them into a container and apply animation it that container div.

Comment: @j809, thank you your valuable comment. But I think then it will toggle `.other_details` div as well with `#myDiv`. Which I don't want.  I just want `#myDiv` to toggle and `.other_details` should be always stay visible.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery .animate()? (http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: @Izzy, good point. But I think if there is direct function available to `toggle()` then I thought why to `animate()` manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used `animate()`

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DSghU/)

```
$(".myButton").click(function () {
var effect = 'width';
var duration = 500;
//if the current width is 200px, then the target width is 0px otherwise the target width is 200px
var targetWidth = $('#myDiv').css("width")=="200px"?"0px":"200px";
//Check if the div was hidden then display it
if(!$("#myDiv").is(":visible")){
     $("#myDiv").show();   
}
$('#myDiv').animate({width: targetWidth},duration,function(){
    if($(this).css("width")=="0px"){
         $(this).hide();   
    }
    else{
     $(this).show();   
    }
});
});
```

I have modified the CSS for `#myDiv` and added

```
overflow:hidden;
```

**Edit:**

I have modified the "margin-left" property instead of the "width" property

check out the updated version at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DSghU/2/)

```
$(".myButton").click(function () {
var effect = 'width';
var duration = 500;
//get the outer width of the div
var divOuterWidth= $("#myDiv").outerWidth();
divOuterWidth+= 8; //the margin on the body element

var targetMargin = $('#myDiv').css("margin-left")==((-divOuterWidth)+"px")?"0px":(-divOuterWidth)+"px";

$('#myDiv').animate({marginLeft: targetMargin},duration);
});
```

Comment: 1+ for the answer and effort. But the problem here i'm facing is, its re-sizing `#myDiv` so its content is coming down and its increasing its height to fit to content (which obviously will interfere other elements in my website and responsiveness). I want "Moving Slide" effect instead "Resize". :)

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check if this is what you need :)

Comment: Thank you very much for perfect answer. This one is quite shorter that previous one. So I really liked solution you provided... +1111 :)